# How to override @CreatedDate in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, jodatime

I have two mongo collections, one is the Foo collection and another is the FooHistory collection.
The Foohistory collection is an exact copy of the Foo collection but it creates every time a new document upon every change in the Foo collection.

in the Foo collection, the POJO class has a CreatedOn field that is annotated with @CreatedDate. so every time a document is inserted in the Foohistory collection, it is being inserted with currentDate. My requirement is, I want to use the same Foo collection CreatedOn time for all the histories by leveraging the @CreatedDate annotation, can someone help me with this?

The structure of POJO classes are

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Foo {
    
    @Id
    private String id;
    private LocalDate CreatedOn;
    
}


public class FooHistory {
    
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Foo foo;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an `EntityListener` and annotate the `FooHistory` with `@EntityListeners`. The `EntityListener` should implement the logic to retrieve all `FooHistory` documents and update `foo.CreatedOn` recursively. The real feasibility depends on the `FooHistory` collection size.